# Extracting values from a dictionary to a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to save the data from a dictionary to a file, my code is:

```
mapping = {'a': 1, 'c': 5, 'b': 3, 'd': -4}    
values = {'sample1': {'a': 12, 'c': 4, 'b': 10, 'd': 6}, 'sample3': {'a': 3, 'c': 9, 'b': 6, 'd': 10}, 'sample2': {'a': 5, 'c': 6, 'b': 8, 'd': 12}}

for dataset in values:
    for key, value in mapping.items():
        values[dataset][key] += value
    with open(dataset + ".txt", 'w') as out:
        out.write(dataset)
        for key,value in values[dataset]:
            out.write("{0},{1}\n".format(key,value))
```

but when I run it, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for key,value in values[dataset]:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Any idea/hints on what is wrong?

Cheers,Kate

Comment: Since `values[dataset]` returns a `dict`, I think your looking for `for key, value in values[dataset].items():`

Comment: Also, to fix such mistakes yourself, you should either use a debugger to see what your code does step by step, or maybe use a simple `print` statement like `print values[dataset]` before the line that throws the error to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for key,value in values[dataset]:
```

to

```
for key,value in values[dataset].items():
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are missing the **items** attribute in the last *for*.

Without knowing what you want to accomplish, I would write it like this:

```
mapping = {'a': 1, 'c': 5, 'b': 3, 'd': -4}
values = {'sample1': {'a': 12, 'c': 4, 'b': 10, 'd': 6}, 'sample3': {'a': 3, 'c': 9, 'b': 6, 'd': 10}, 'sample2': {'a': 5, 'c': 6, 'b': 8, 'd': 12}}

for dataset in values:
    for key, value in mapping.items():
        values[dataset][key] += value
    with open(dataset + ".txt", 'w') as out:
        out.write("{0}\n".format(dataset)) # for formatting purposes
                                           # although you already have it in the file name
        for key, value in values[dataset].items():
            out.write("{0},{1}\n".format(key,value))
```